# Set Composite Component attribute with a js function

Tags: javascript, html, composite-component

I have a composite component, which has an attribute that reffers to the width of the component, this width varies within the screen size so I have a Js function that calculates the proper value to set that attribute. Problem is that I don't know how to set the Js function in the attribute of the Composite component; here's my code...

```
<h:form id="formSlider" style="width: 100%">
      <comp:sliderComponent images="#{sliderShowBean.sliderList}"
                slideSpeed="2000" width="#{getContWidth}" />
</h:form>
```

With Js function

```
    function getContWidth() {
        var width = $("#content_container_wide").css("width");
        return width;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

If youre talking about JSF check this...

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/j-jsf2fu2/index.html?ca=drs